# How do I deploy user configurations to multiple linux desktops (gnome)?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, deployment

We have been using linux/debian/gnome exclusively in our small office for the past 7 years, and it has always been manageable with 3-4 desktops and 1 server. Recently, we have expanded a little (8 desktops), effectively tripling the support requests at my address, many times because I forgot some obscure setting on the new user accounts.
Is there a way to automatically create and distribute a gconf when a new user is added to our network? We are already using NFS for our ~ and LDAP for our user accounts.
I'm thinking about these kinds of settings: imap(server/username/password), smtp(server/username/password), caldav(server/username/password/delegates), etc.
Google doesn't seem to help: in the Gnome2-days there was a tool called 'Sabayon', but I cannot find anything on it, and I have found a document stating the future possibility of deploying gconf through LDAP, but that also apparently leads to nowhere... How are al those giant deployments organised? This cannot be done manually, but maybe it's just a collection of hacks?

Comment: Come to think of it: I forgot to add that I might need different solutions for these components: gnome (evolution, empathy, maybe some visual stuff like wallpaper), libreoffice and firefox

Comment: In the meanwhile I have discovered [Mozilla Mission Control](http://blog.deanandadie.net/2010/04/an-introduction-to-mission-control-desktop/"), doing exactly what I need for both Firefox and Thunderbird (Iceweasel and Icedove).